# scope array property on ng-repeat element only binds once

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've created a copy of one of the ng-repeat examples on the angular homepage here http://jsfiddle.net/atW32/1/

```
<li ng-repeat="todo in todos" data-id="{{todo.id}}" id="item-{{todo.id}}" data-testA="{{testValue}}" data-testB="{{testValue}}" >
```

What I've added is an ID field to the todo object and attempted to write it out twice one the repeating LI.  It seems that only the last {{todo.id}} gets data bound, the first instance still shows the double curlys.  As you will see it works fine inside of the LI but not on the LI itself.  It also works for single scope vars not in the repeat array.

Is it not possible to render an array var twice on an ng-repeat element?

Comment: The output I saw on your fiddle was this "First ID write:1, Second ID write:1" and "First ID write:2, Second ID write:2". What are you expecting?

Comment: It was the attributes on the LI itself so you have to inspect element to view them.  gab has answered my question.  Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"data-id" and "id" tags are the same for Angular:
Taken from the Angularjs [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> The normalization process is as follows:
>
> **Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes.** Convert
>   the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.